# Predict if a given protein can pass through the intestine

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, protein-structure

Assume that i have a 3d-protein structure in a PDB file on a computer.
Is there any bioinformatic method to predict if that protein can [pass through the intestine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56131/can-proteins-peptides-pass-through-the-intestine/) or not?

Comment: No, you can only make such prediction with experimental data, such as pH stability and vulnerability studies with the relevant proteases.

Comment: You could start with a structural BLAST search, so a BLAST search against the Protein databank and look through the significant matches and search whether these can pass through the intestine (based on literate e.g.) and then align the PDB file of this BLAST match with yours. This will at least give you some information and as suggested by Jeppe further information could probably only be found using experiments.

Comment: @RickBeeloo that's a very smart idea.Thank you very much!